# Not able to INSERT data with Doctrine2 DBAL\Connection in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I am trying to insert some data in a MySQL table with Doctrine2 DBAL\Connection (**for tables that I don't want to be mapped**), with this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class UtilsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/utils/fixer", name="utils_fixer")
     */
    public function dataFixer(Connection $conn)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test(id, username) VALUES (':id', ':name')";

        $id = 456;
        $name = 'blabla';

        $res = $conn->executeUpdate($sql, ['id' => $id, 'name' => $name]);

        return $this->render('utils/index.html.twig', ['res' => $res]);
    }
}
```

This is what my table looks like:

[image]

This is giving me: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ':id' for column 'id' at row 1".

**The Id field has no auto increment**, it's just a test table.

SELECT statement is returning data OK.

Value binding doesn't seem to work ??

I used this Doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html).

Comment: The manual talks about a $types array as a third argument to executeUpdate but, sadly, does not present an example.  Add ['\PDO::PARAM_INT,PDO::PARAM_STR] and see if that helps.  The error message does seem a bit strange though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholders shouldn't be quoted.

At least this gives a usage example of the **executeUpdate()** method.

```
public function dataFixer(Connection $conn)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test(id, username) VALUES (:id, :name)";

    $id = 456;
    $name = 'blabla';

    $res = $conn->executeUpdate($sql, ['id' => $id, 'name' => $name]);

    return $this->render('utils/index.html.twig', ['res' => $res]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not insert the value of $id if that value is autoincrement - as i think it is.

Comment: No there is no auto increment, it's just a plain integer field. No primary key, no index.